# Does GZip support multi-part file compression?

Tags: gzip, 7zip

I have been looking around if Gzip supports multi-part file compression. From what I have seen so far it does not, but how come 7z allows multipart compression when Gzip is selected as the compression? Does this mean 7z takes care of multi-partitioning internally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gzip doesn't support multipart archives, but you can still create them using `split`:

```
split -–bytes=20m /path/to/large/archive /path/to/output/files
```

Now, to put it back together, just `cat` the parts together into one:

```
cat files* > archive
```

As far as I can tell, this is what 7-zip does when creating archives. It might add some header information, but it basically just dumps exactly 20mb of data into a file and appends a number after the name. Then, internally, it just assembles the parts and reads that as an archive.

Comment: Tried this out with a large Wireshark log I had to split to email to someone, and it seems to work (at least I can reassemble and use the resulting file on my box).

Comment: @T.E.D.: No reason why it wouldn't. The contents of the file don't change.

Comment: 7-zip doesn't add extra header info.  Naming part files consistent with 7-zips convention, e.g. myfile.gz.001, myfile.gz.002, allows to conveniently open and extract it using 7-zip.